# Question on the definition of a ring.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, definition

A ring $\langle R,+, \cdot\rangle $ is a set $R$ with two binary operations such that:

1. $\langle R,+\rangle $ is an abelian group.
2. Multiplication is associative.
3. Left and right distributive laws hold.

Can someone give me an example where the left distributive law holds but the right one doesn't?

Comment: Not related to the problem at hand, but: Your definition doesn't require a multiplicative identity?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Some authors do this. My first algebra book did not require identities.

Comment: yes, one can always embed a ring without unit into one that does have one.

Comment: @rotten The main issue comes with defining ring homomorphisms (most authors require they send $1$ to $1$, for pretty good reasons).

Answer (score 6):

Consider the set of affine maps from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R$ under addition and composition. We have right-distributivity as for affine maps $ax+b,cx+d,ex+f$ we get
$$a(cx+d)+b+e(cx+d)+f=(a+e)(cx+d)+(b+f)$$
but not left-distributivity as
$$a(cx+d+ex+f)+b\neq a(cx+d)+b+a(ex+f)+b$$
when $b\neq 0$. We can make it left-distributive but not right-distributive by simply reversing the order of composition.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Thanks, good point.

Comment: Certainly a cleaner example then mine, and it fits a pattern - function composition is a problem for distributive laws on one side :)

Comment: @AlexBecker why do you have two $b$'s on the RHS of the last equation?

Answer (score 5):

Consider the set of polynomials with integer coefficients, with addition defined as usual, but multiplication defined as composition:

$$(f\times g)(x) = f(g(x))$$

Then $(f+g)\times h = f\times h + g\times h$, but $h\times (f+g)\neq h\times f + h\times g$ in general.

For example, if $f(x)=x$ and $h(x)=x^2$ then $((f+f)\times h)(x) = 2x^2 = (f\times h)(x) + f\times h(x)$.  On the other hand, $h\times(f+f)(x) = 4x^2\neq 2x^2=h\times f(x) + h\times f(x)$.

i'm not sure if this is left- or right-distributive, but if $(R,+,\times)$ is right-distributive, you can create a left-distributive ring $(R,+,\times_{opp})$ with $a\times_{opp} b = b\times a$.